# What is best way to create converter from function?

Tags: c#

I want to apply func object as converter like this:

```
Func<int, double> f = x => x / 2.5;
Converter<int, double> convert = f;
List<double> applied_list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3}.ConvertAll(convert);
```

Compiler gives me such message:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func' to 'System.Converter'

What is best way to use function as converter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three options here. In my preferred order, they are:

- Start using LINQ instead of `ConvertAll`:

  ```
  List<double> appliedList = new List { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(f).ToList();
  ```
- Create a converter to start with:

  ```
  Converter<int, double> converter = x => x / 2.5;
  List<double> appliedList = new List { 1, 2, 3 }.ConvertAll(converter);
  ```
- If you really, really must, create a converter from the function using a delegate creation expression:

  ```
  Func<int, double> f = x => x / 2.5;
  Converter<int, double> converter = new Converter<int, double>(f);
  List<double> appliedList = new List { 1, 2, 3 }.ConvertAll(converter);
  ```

The last option creates a delegate that just wraps the original one.

Answer (score 5):

Using `var converter = new Converter<int, double>(f)`, or by simply using `Select()` for mapping instead:

```
var appliedList = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3 }.Select(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use `.ConvertAll` instead of `.Select` then implement a simple workaround to convert `Func` to delegate `Converter` in following way:

```
    Func<int, double> f = x => x / 2.5;
    Converter<int, double> convert = x => f(x);
    List<double> applied_list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }.ConvertAll(convert);
```